# how to display selected item from Spinner using string Buffer in android

Tags: android

```
public class AddCourse extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Spinner addCourse;
    String addedcoursevalue;
    TextView AddcourseButton;
    StringBuffer sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcourse);

        addCourse = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        AddcourseButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AddcourseButton);
        AddcourseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        final String[] coursearray = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.Course_arrays);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, coursearray);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        addCourse.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        addCourse.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                addedcoursevalue = addCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(addedcoursevalue);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(AddCourse.this, sb, 1000).show();

    }

}
```

This is my code i am able to display value in spinner i want what ever i selected that should store in buffer that i want to Print on Button click in toast please check where am doing mistake please help

Comment: used `String Builder` instead of `Buffer`

Comment: @MD But i am unable to display all data what ever i selected its display only last selected data

Comment: Go and search on Google _How to append string in string builder_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want what ever i selected that should store in buffer that i want to
>   Print on Button click

No need to store Spinner selected value in Buffer inside `onItemSelected` method. you can directly access selected value in `onClick` method by calling `addCourse.getSelectedItem()` :

```
    sb = new StringBuffer(); 
    addCourse.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            addedcoursevalue = addCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();
            sb.append(addedcoursevalue);
        }
```

Comment: but i want all selected value suppose i have select x now again i have select y now again i have selected z now if i click on button then it should display XYZ

Comment: @user1531170: see my edit answer. move `sb = new StringBuffer(); ` outside `onItemSelected`

Comment: SelectedText.setText(sb+"\n");  But unable to display text in textview with next Line when i selecte

Comment: @user1531170: change `sb.append(addedcoursevalue);` to `sb.append(addedcoursevalue+"\n");`